# Can't place OPTION (Recompile) after WHERE Clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to put Option Recompile after the WHERE Clause but keeps failing with Syntax error: `Incorrect Syntax near recompile. Expecting ( or SELECT`

Here is my sql code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE Code = @Code AND Activity = 'T'  OPTION (RECOMPILE))
```

I know in many cases if there is no AND condition it would have worked. I have searched all over online for a solution without any helpful info. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the point for using recompile here anyway? This will force the database to recompute the execution plan for each execution of the query, which seems suboptimal in this case.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? SQL has no `IF`, but PSM (aka stored procedures) has.

Comment: @GMB Yes, I know that, but there seem to be parameter sniffing happening. This query is part of a huge stored procedure and when I diagnose the longest running query, this is the query that comes up. Hopefully that answers your question?

Comment: `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is used when you don't want to cache bad plans for other version of the same query (often seen when you have query with a `WHERE` like `(Col1 = @Col1 OR @Col1 IS NULL) AND (Col2 = @Col2 OR @Col2 IS NULL) AND ...`. There's no need for it there.

Comment: *"but there seem to be parameter sniffing happening"* if there is, I suspect it's more likely to be in the query inside your `IF`, not the subquery in the `EXISTS`.

Comment: Isn't `option recompile` supposed to go at the very end?

Comment: What if you use [`with recompile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure) instead?

Comment: @Larnu - if they have sub optimal indexing it could be this statement. e.g. If they have a non covering index on just  `Activity ` they might end up with a plan with a ton of lookups when compiled for a very common `@Code` but executed for a highly selective one

Comment: True, @MartinSmith , I just suspected that the query in the `IF` is a more likely candidate, especially as we can't see it and it's more likely to be more complex that the query we had.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the comments, If I run my stored proc via the app it takes 8 seconds and if I run it in SSMS directly it takes less than a second, regarding the query inside the IF, will have to check

Comment: You mean you haven't checked already what the slow running statement is? This should be the first step. If you have query store available this is easy to do. - otherwise look at `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a limitation of the SQL grammar.

There is no way to place query hints next to statements in an `IF`.

You can use

```
DECLARE @Result BIT

SELECT @Result = CASE
                   WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM   Table1
                                WHERE  Code = @Code
                                       AND Activity = 'T') THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                 END
OPTION (RECOMPILE);

IF @Result = 1
  BEGIN
      TODO:
  END
```

If you have an index on `Code, Activity` or `Activity, Code` you shouldn't need this anyway as then it can always use a plan with a simple seek

Comment: Thanks Martin, let me check your query and will update you

Comment: No need to update me. I have answered the question you asked. If you have a new question ask  a new question.